# On Some Stack Exchange Sites, a Draft of the Question is Automatically Saved. How is it Possible to Retrieve the Full Draft From a Different Location?

Tags: support

I have this feedback for one of the questions that I asked that I feel is a very difficult question for me to answer.  It is not that the problem itself seems impossible.  Rather, the solution has multiple aspects to it, and each aspect takes me some time to complete.  Also, I tend to notice small typos that need correction over and over:

> Stephen Elliott - Hi, (a) FYI, the number of edits you've made has
> started to trigger alerts. While they seem relevant, please note that
> each edit bumps your question to the top of the active list, so each
> edit also pushes everything else on that list down. Therefore doing
> many, small edits is discouraged, in favour of a smaller number of
> larger edits i.e. fewer bumps. (b) You seem to have the text
> "Introduction to he Applicable Data" as the last line. Is that
> intended? (c) Personally for me, your actual question is now hidden in
> the commentary. Perhaps consider highlighting it? –  SamGibson ♦ Dec
> 19, 2023 at 14:51

I remember that on some Stack Exchange websites, that a draft is automatically saved every so often.

1. Is there that automatically saved draft here on Electronics Stack Exchange?
2. Do the number of auto-save drafts contribute to the number of edits, or is just the number of "Posted" Questions or Answers that flag trigger alerts?
3. If I do not have the draft text in front of me, what are the detailed steps that I need to do in order to access that draft again (with its text filled in in the section to edit it)?  I think that I am a little confused on this point, because when I access the draft it is usually from the latest Posted version.  I cannot accessed the latest saved version because that *I suspect that I do not know how to*. I do not know how to get it from the latest saved draft complete with the text to be edited in the top box.  Perhaps if I better understand how to do this, that could avoid all of the difficulties.
4. How can the automatic draft-save be tested to make sure that it really includes everything necessary before adjustments needed to a full Question or Answer update?
5. Are there any other suggestions about how to take care of a Problem or Solution that requires a lot of work in different sections and updates one-at-a-time, as well as several small typo-corrections?
6. I tried waiting awhile for the draft to auto-save.  But when I bring up the link for the "edit" in a separate tab, it reverts to the previously posted version and not the auto-save.  It seems that auto-save of the drafts might be disabled here.  Is that right?  Or is there some sort of special key sequence or something like that needed to get that to work?

Thank you for your help and support!

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with continuously updating and polishing a question, _as long as you don't change the intent_. Like editing and asking an entirely different question suddenly. The comment by a moderator was just a head's up that too many edits are frowned upon since it could be considered "bumping", ie trying to draw more attention to the question through edits. What I find helpful personally when posting large posts, is to scroll down below the edit box and proof read the preview, to weed out minor typos etc before posting.

Comment: What you could do however, is to consider if the large question could be split in several. For example you could perhaps have split your question in two post: the theory part and the "how can I do that in LTSpice part" with a link to the first question. This also means that you might get better answers - someone might be an expert on the theory but not on LTSpice, or vice versa.

Comment: @Lundin :  I have to confess that I do not understand the privileges for Stack Exchange Electronics very well.  Currently I have a reputation of 11, and I need to add graphs as well as tables to the current question to clarify it.  If I ever get to the stage that I feel that I have indeed answered the question on my own, then I would need to be able to cut and paste these into the answers.  I am worried about if I start breaking the question into smaller questions that it might lower my reputation so that I am not able to paste the picture graphs or other consequences.  What are the limits?

Comment: The ability to post graphs or pictures is not tied to reputation. You probably shouldn't mess around with this specific question even more - I was rather giving advice for how to ask a question next time.

Comment: You will only get blocked from asking questions if you ask a lot of them and a large portion are poorly received. For example some kid repeatedly posting their low effort homework questions here will eventually get question banned. And each well-received question (up-voted, accepted answer etc) will raise the bar for that question ban. I don't think you need to worry about that :)

Comment: @Lundin : what about pictures?  The graphs have to be screen-captured.  I had troubles on a different site posting inline graphs because I did not have enough reputation at the time.  What are the limits on graphics posting versus reputation?

Comment: There should be no such restrictions AFAIK. You can view all reputation-tied privileges here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges. There might be the "new user restrictions" privilege preventing certain things perhaps? That's basically an anti-spammer mechanism. You have 11 rep now so you will have unlocked that one.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Is there that automatically saved draft here on Electronics Stack Exchange?

There are, but only for new questions/answers, not for edits. Please see details here: [What are the details/implementation of the draft feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111050/what-are-the-details-implementation-of-the-draft-feature) So given that you are a logged in, registred user, drafts should be saved server-side. However, changes made during the last couple of minutes may not be saved.

> 2. Do the number of auto-save drafts contribute to the number of edits

No.

> or is just the number of "Posted" Questions or Answers that flag trigger alerts?

It's the amount of edits on the already posted question live on the site that would trigger such alerts - but only to moderators. The purpose of such alerts is to notify moderators in case someone is making multiple minor edits for the purpose of "bumping" the question to receive more attention, which is frowned upon.

> 3. If I do not have the draft text in front of me, what are the detailed steps that I need to do in order to access that draft again (with its text filled in in the section to edit it)?

Given that it is a new question and you haven't yet posted it, the draft should be available if you are logged in and click "Ask Question".

> 4. How can the automatic draft-save be tested to make sure that it really includes everything necessary before adjustments needed to a full Question or Answer update?

Not sure if I understand what you are asking here. By proof-reading?

> 5. Are there any other suggestions about how to take care of a Problem or Solution that requires a lot of work in different sections and updates one-at-a-time, as well as several small typo-corrections?

Well, there is the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) on the main meta where you can post stuff just to experiment for formatting etc.

> 6. I tried waiting awhile for the draft to auto-save. But when I bring up the link for the "edit" in a separate tab, it reverts to the previously posted version and not the auto-save. It seems that auto-save of the drafts might be disabled here. Is that right? Or is there some sort of special key sequence or something like that needed to get that to work?

As per the link I posted, it seems that drafts of edits are not auto saved. Auto save apparently only works until you have posted the question live.

---

In general, https://meta.stackexchange.com/ is the best place to ask about network-wide site mechanics such as auto saves etc. That site is read by Community Managers, devs and lots of veteran mods. If you want feedback on a specific post here on Electrical Engineering, then this meta is the correct place to ask though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I am still reviewing and testing the relevant parts to make sure I understand everything correctly and can implement it well before giving you the "check" up-vote on the answer.   I appreciate your patience as I have very limited times to make progress on that review of the various parts.